# Apply function to array of decimals

Tags: c#, array, comparative-review

I am writing some code to transform an array of decimals so that they are [discounted](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/discounting.asp) over time.

I initially wrote the following code:

```
private decimal[] deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    decimal[] deflatedItems = new decimal[items.Count()];

    decimal factorAdjustment = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        deflatedItems[i] = items[i] / factorAdjustment;
        factorAdjustment = factorAdjustment * (1 + deflateRate);
    }

    return deflatedItems;
}
```

Then I realised that instead of having the `factorAdjustment` variable, I can just use to the power of:

```
private decimal[] deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    decimal[] deflatedItems = new decimal[items.Count()];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        deflatedItems[i] = items[i] / (decimal)Math.Pow((double)(1 + deflateRate), i);
    }

    return deflatedItems;
}
```

As `Math.Pow()` only accepts and returns `double`s, I think it's easier to create a wrapper function for it:

```
private decimal PowerOf(decimal x, decimal y)
{
    return (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x, (double)y);
}
```

and then simplify:

```
private decimal[] deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    decimal[] deflatedItems = new decimal[items.Count()];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        deflatedItems[i] = items[i] / PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, i);
    }

    return deflatedItems;
}
```

Then I realised that I really just want to transform the array and don't need a second array:

```
private void deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i] = items[i] / PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, i);
    }
}
```

and then I can simplify this to:

```
private void deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i] /= PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, i);
    }
}
```

so my final version is:

```
private void deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i] /= PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, i);
    }
}

private decimal PowerOf(decimal x, decimal y)
{
    return (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x, (double)y);
}
```

I'm sure it can probably done in a one-liner by someone who is cleverer than me. Which version is the most easily understood?

I am not really worried about the performance as the array of items will only ever have 100 or 200 items and it's never done in a loop.

Comment: @Lachlan Barclay your final version and original do not give the same result. In the original, the first item is discounted by 1 + deflateRate, but, in the final version, the first item is discounted by `PowerOf(1m + deflateRate, i)` where i == 0.  This gives a divisor of 1.

Comment: Thanks @AlanT :) Someone else found that bug a few days later!!! I'll fix up the code :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arguably a better variant for DeflateArray:

```
private decimal[] DeflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    return items
        .Select((item, index) => item /= PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, index))
        .ToArray();
}
```

It's better in a way it helps [avoiding OBOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

And by the way, another thing you can do is define it as an extension method in a separate static class, and will be able to invoke it as `myArrayOfDecimals.DeflateArrayWithRate(1.5m)`:

```
public static class DecimalArrayExtensions
{
    public static decimal[] DeflateArrayWithRate(this decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
    {
        return items
            .Select((item, index) => item /= PowerOf(1 + deflateRate, index))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static decimal PowerOf(decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        return (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x, (double)y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your original.  It is more efficient and reads clearly to me. It would be an edge edge case but you could have a `factorAdjustment`  that is not represented perfect as double.

Don't use both `Count()` and `Length`.

```
private decimal[] deflateArray(decimal[] items, decimal deflateRate)
{
    int count = items.Count();
    decimal[] deflatedItems = new decimal[count];

    decimal factorAdjustment = 1 + deflateRate;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        deflatedItems[i] = items[i] / factorAdjustment;
        factorAdjustment *= (1 + deflateRate);
    }

    return deflatedItems;
}
```